# Синонимизировать метки [сервер] и [server]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно [server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) сделать синонимом [сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: А разве пользователи не могут сами предлагать синонимизацию тегов?

Comment: @Vesper, для этого нужно иметь репутацию по тегу. По этому тегу у меня нет репутации

Comment: Успел забыть, что репутация нужна. Хмм. Видимо, поэтому [badge:synonymizer] такая редкая медаль - на основном сайте всего 668, здесь вообще 7 всего.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синоним  [server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) → [сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80) добавлен.